# MySQL - JOIN data from two columns into one output

Tags: mysql, join

First time posting to stack, so apologies if I screw something up.

I have a table of data in MySQL that I'll call Table1. This Table has time stamps for when a transaction goes live, and when that same transaction is closed out. I can run two separate queries (seen below) to generate a count for the amount transactions **created** per hour (Query1), and the amount of transactions **resolved** per hour (Query2) - If I combine the queries, I can get the data I need starting at hour 4 (when people begin work) but I need the data for transactions created before then so I can create a comprehensive output that shows our total transactions incoming (starting at hour 0) and showing how many we're completing (starting at hour 4).

Query1

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%H') AS 'Hour', COUNT(DISTINCT(created_at)) AS Queued
>   
> FROM Table1
>   
> WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%d-%Y') = '04-02-2017'
>   
> GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%H');

Query2

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(resolved_at, '%H') AS 'Hour', COUNT(DISTINCT resolved_at) AS 'Worked'
>   
> FROM Table1
>   
> WHERE DATE_FORMAT(resolved_at, '%m-%d-%Y') = '04-02-2017'
>   
> GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(resolved_at, '%H');

If I run Query 3, it pulls the right data from hours 4 - 23 (when we're staffed) but I can't successfully get hours 0-3

Query3

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(resolved_at, '%H') AS 'Hour', COUNT(DISTINCT resolved_at) AS 'Worked', COUNT(DISTINCT created_at) as 'Queued'
>   
> FROM Table1
>   
> WHERE DATE_FORMAT(resolved_at, '%m-%d-%Y') = '04-02-2017'
>   
> GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(resolved_at, '%H');

Thank you! I tried post an example of the output, but couldnt get the formatting right.

Comment: could you post a row from Table1 with column headings or is it too large?

Comment: Can't figure out how to make it look good, uploaded a screenshot of it: http://imgur.com/a/aZ0L7

Comment: Am I correct that the events before work have not been resolved so for the events that are before work, what would the resolved_at field be?  Does it have a default value you could look for or set if you dont have one

Comment: From what I gather, this data is populated after the day, so by the time it's written to the table, it has a created_at and a resolved_at, otherwise I think it's NULL. Essentially, the event_hash_id is the transaction, it gets queued (created_at) and sits there until someone finishes it (resolved_at)  - I'll submit images of Query1/2/3 outputs and what I'm HOPING to see (the last image) http://imgur.com/a/ec5aD

Comment: What I tried (unsuccessfully) was running sub-queries, one to generate Queued and one to generate Worked, and I tried to LEFT JOIN them to create an output, so that if Worked didn't have a 0 hour, it would still join on the table - I'm able to export both queries to Excel and then VLOOKUP to get what I need, but if it can be done in one query I can more successfully roll it out to people who can copy/paste and execute

Comment: its hard to tell without being able to see full structure but could you do something like a FULL OUTER JOIN .......WHERE(resolved_at,'%m-%d-%Y') = '04-02-2017' AND status = 'whatever it is by default' that would only return items that have been created but not looked at yet?

Comment: I'll try it out for sure, thank you! I'm at a standstill now so I'll try whatever - if it works, I'll let you know.

Comment: if status does not have a default value you could do WHERE... NOT status ='reject' AND NOT status= 'accepted' AND....covering all other status I am a php/web developer no SQL master so matching any record from either table that did not have a processed status is all that comes to mind